# Is the python mechanize cache feature the same as normal browser cache feature?

Tags: python, mechanize

In its document, it says "This caching behaviour can be avoided by using `Mechanize.OpenerDirector`". Does this cache influence next request of the same page?

Comment: hey, did you get all the info you need from my answer?

Comment: I've turned away from this topic after a week, and haven't touched this area ever since. I've forgotten the context of this problem and cannot make a convincing response on your answer. I'd better delay the decision until I hava the chance to do the job again. Maybe someone else could provide a vote.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the "caching" the documentation refers to is talking about seekable responses, not a browser-like cache feature.  For example:

```
total_nr_bytes = len(response.get_data())
assert len(response.read()) == total_nr_bytes
assert len(response.read()) == 0  # we've already read the data
response.seek(0)
assert len(response.read()) == total_nr_bytes
```

It is caching the data after you call `.read()` in the python object, **not** caching the page itself if you request a page again.

Short answer: no it will not affect the next request of the same page